# How to scan codebase for completion suggestions with Monaco Editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm writing an Electron (or Tauri) app that uses Monaco Editor.

Autocomplete does present suggestions from the current document as well from the language you're working in, but I'm not sure how to have it provide suggestions from arbitrary files.

Let's say I have a specific folder on my computer full of code that I'd like to provide suggestions from. How can I tell Monaco Editor to scan that folder so it can provide suggestions?